# django timesince should display seconds as well

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django. I am trying to create a blog with Django 1.8.

On my index page, everything is fine with 'timesince' filter for templates. But when a new blog is created, it shows '0 minutes'. I want to be able to display the number of seconds since it was created if it is less than 1 minute since the blog has been created. Please help me out.

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2275/

Comment: i passed to the template, a context variable 'posts' which contains all the posts after querying the database and included in the template as follows.  {% for p in posts %}
   <a href="posts/{{ p.id }}/{{ p.slug }}">{{ p.text }}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#66ff99">{{ p.created_at|timesince}} ago</span><br><br>
  {% endfor %}

Comment: In the default implementation of `timesince`, minutes is the smallest unit, you can use a custom tag (like @GlynJackson suggested) in order to do the same.

Comment: thanks friends for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Rahul's answer is correct, `timesince` does not support "seconds" output.

But Django's Humanize template filter library has `naturaltime` which should do what you're after.

To use it, in your template:

```
<!-- At the top of your file -->
{% load humanize %}

<!-- then.. -->
{{ date_time_value|naturaltime }}
```

See the [humanize docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime).

Answer (score 0):

Django `timesince` template tag does not provide the functionality of displaying `seconds` also. The smallest unit used is `minutes`.

From [`timesince` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince):

> **Minutes is the smallest unit used**, and `“0 minutes”` will be returned
>   for any date that is in the future relative to the comparison point.